# ‘Thankin' God that you weren't here’

Tags: reported-speech, indirect-objects

> September saw a month of tears
> And thankin' God that you weren't here
> To see me like that

Is “God” indirect object?

[Tim McGraw](https://genius.com/3485304/Taylor-swift-tim-mcgraw/September-saw-a-month-of-tears-and-thankin-god-that-you-werent-here-to-see-me-like-that)
<sub>By Taylor Swift</sub>

Comment: Is there a reason why you are asking if the term "God" is an indirect object? Why couldn't it be a direct object?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Because I think that-clause is a direct object.

Comment: It's the other way round. The speaker thanks God (direct object) _for_ the fact that the person was not present.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! "God" is the direct object. The *that*-clause is a catenative complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"God" is the direct object of the verb "thanking"  (a verb in  gerund/participle form) "thanking" is pronounced as thankin', but that is just a casual contraction

The phrase "thanking God that you weren't here to see me like that" is the object of the verb "saw" in a parallel construction  ("September saw a month of tears"  and "September saw thankin' God ...")